# From Design to Development: Is there a common EmberJS workflow?

Tags: ember.js, workflow, ember-app-kit, ember-cli

This question is subjective by nature, but I am curious about a specific thing, so hopefully there is a decent answer.

I tend to be a little old fashioned and like to create all my pages static and get the design just the way I like it (or at least very close) before I start breaking it down into handlebars and components and templates.  This is mostly because the Ember "Getting Started" Guide taught me that process.

Is this the common practice, generally?

I am the front-end Designer and Developer for my company, and basically I have two separate workflows, one for Design, and one for Development/Testing.

Is there a way to merge the two and get a single streamlined workflow (perhaps a JS task that can split up static pages into templates by using some special markup??)

Design tends to be a little easier when you are working with static pages.
Development (especially when using EAK or Ember-CLI) expects everything to be modular and dynamic.

Is there any clear answer to this question?

I posted a similar question on [Ember Forums](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/opinions-on-best-ember-workflow/5542), but have not gotten many view, so I figured I would try here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer when you're building an app with Ember you want to build around the URL structure, due to the way the URL and Router interact.  Here's an awesome talk by Tom Dale about the URL.  This makes it a very outside in approach, since each layer deeper in the url is content that's generally embedded 1 level deeper in the page.

http://vimeo.com/68390483

Comment: That video was pretty awesome.  I suppose I need to start thinking a little more modular... perhaps sketch out a sort of site map with all the listed URLs and work down from there....